Testing the effect of a continious IV on DV, in order to explain group differences
I would like to ask a question regarding an analysis I’m planning and it might be a basic question so, apologies in advane.... To describe the situation: There are two groups of participants in my experiment (categorical IV group: G1 and G2) completing a task where they are supposed to rate e.g the distress level (DV) of 2 different conditions (categorical IV condition : C1 and C2) . It’s a repeated measures design.
Firstly, I hypothesize that the contrast of the ratings (C1 vs C2) will be higher in the G1 vs G2 and test it with this model:
lmer(distress ~ condition*group+ (1|subject), data = data)
I also have another IV, which is continuous (let’s say X).  And important to note here, that there are many other ratings other than the distress.
My idea is that, in case this group effect turns out significant, I would like to further test the extent that this X variable accounts for group differences. However, group effect might turn out to be not significant. Thus, I came up with two options:
If there is NOT a group effect: I will analyse the effect of X across all subjects without using “group” as an additional fixed effect, but will do this only on those DVs that did not show group differenecs (because my idea is that if there is no group effect, maybe X explains the differences across individuals instead):
lmer(DVs that did not differ between groups~ condition*X+ (1|subject), data = data)
If there IS a group effect: I will analyse the effect of X only in the group of interest (so, G2; because for my research it would be the relevant finding to further investigate; i.e. why GS showed smaller difference between conditions and to what extent X accounts for this). So, I would analyse it with the following formula (bascially the same as above), using only the participants in G2:
lmer(DVs that differed between groups~ condition*X+ (1|subject), data = data)
So, my questions would be:

Is there any part in the plan described above that does not seem logical?
Should I first run such a model...
lmer(distress ~ condition*group + X + (1|subject), data = data)
... in order to further analyse the effect of X in G2? In another words, would that be a pre-requisite for the analysis I described above? Or rather not?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Abbreviations IV and DV are not used in this way everywhere, so it would help if you could explain them explicitly. (I can guess what they mean but don't leave guesswork to the reader!)

In my view you overinterpret the difference between "significant" and "not significant". Note that an insignificant result does not mean that the null hypothesis is true, i.e., that there is no effect. Note also that the significance cutoff (I suspect you want to use 5%) is basically arbitrary and the "message of the data" is very similar for p-values, say, 0.042 (significant) and 0.058 (insignificant). This means that assessing evidence regarding a null hypothesis by a test is rather a continuous affair than a binary one, so saying that you do a different analysis if some p is 0.042 rather than 0.058 is not a good idea. Furthermore, making analysis decisions conditionally on the same data on which the conditional analysis is then run will violate model assumptions and is usually invalid.
Also note that the model assumptions of the model excluding variable $X$ imply that there is no further variable that has systematic impact on the results, meaning that if indeed $X$ has an impact (and be it in interaction with other variables), model assumptions of any model that does not include $X$ are usually violated (the word "usually" used here and above means that there are exceptions, but there is no reason to believe that you are in an exceptional situation, so you may just ignore that word).
I'd recommend to run a model that has all potentially relevant variables in it and do all analyses you might be interested in unconditionally, not depending on what comes out significant where.
